# QML calculating text space when changed to bold

Tags: qt, qml

I have a custom tool button where when checked the font become bold. When happens, the size of the text increase and consequently the ToolButton shrink or stretch accordly. How can i pre calculate the correct fixed size for the text inside the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html) QML type for this purpose. Setup the `FontMetrics` object with the same font and style you are using for your text, then call an appropriate method of your `FontMetrics` instance like `boundingRect` or `tightBoundingRect` and resize your button based on the results.

If you just want to keep your ToolButton to a fixed size that can contain the normal and bold font without auto-resizing, you can just get the size for the bold text using the `FontMetrics` instance and set the button size accordingly.

For convenience you can also use [TextMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textmetrics.html) QML type. The advantage is that the `boundingRect` and `tightBoundingRect` are properties and you can bind to them.

The latter is preferred for your use-case.

Comment: using FontMetrics.boundingRect with a font and with the same font with bold true return the same size